# Cleared the files but memory is not reduced

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-management

I am creating an application. I am storing the files in Document directory. And after my work completed, delete the files from document directory as like below:

```
    NSMutableDictionary * Dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]; 
    // Next every file storing into this dictionary like below 
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *baseDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *pathComp = [baseDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"IMG%d.PNG",presentCount]; 
    fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathComp]; 
    [Dictionary setObject:fileURL forKey:fileURL]; 

    while ([[Dictionary allKeys]count]!=0) {
        NSURL *deleteFileURL = [[Dictionary allKeys] lastObject];
        NSLog(@"Path %@",deleteFileURL.path);
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:deleteFileURL.path error:nil];
        [Dictionary removeObjectForKey:deleteFileURL];
    }
```

Here my problem is, after delete the files from document directory, memory is not reduced, still it's occupying as like files exist. Due to this issue, my is crashing. So please help me how to clear the memory.

Actually i am getting the files(Photos ) from the server and first placing in documents directory,and trying to save using photo library.Once i give input from dictionary to photo library, after completion handler, i am trying to delete the file.Its removed and photo saved, but memory is not reduced.

Comment: please provide a line of code where you declare and initialize Dictionary variable

Comment: Dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
Next every file storing into this dictionary like below
      NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                    NSString *baseDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                    NSString *pathComp  = [baseDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"IMG%d.PNG",presentCount];
                   fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathComp];
      [Dictionary setObject:fileURL forKey:fileURL];

Comment: I've noticed you're using uppercase in filenames. You should take into account, iOS filesystem is case sensitive, maybe this causes the problem.

Comment: Is this create any problem?

Comment: I don't know, you should check the code where you store the files into documents folder and make sure you use the same filename convention in both places.

Comment: Please check the return value of `removeItemAtPath`. Also add a parameter for the error to be returned.

Comment: Always returns the True and removed the file from documents directory.

Comment: Do you check memory in Settings -> General -> iPhone storage? sometimes it takes time to reindex used storage. wait for a couple of minutes and check again.

Answer (score 0):

1、Remove the file after checking for the existence of a file on the path, and check the return value of removeItemAtPath: to determine if the deletion succeeded.

```
NSString *path = @"a/b";
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
       BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:nil];
       // Check the success's value
    }
```

Comment: Tried this also,always returned 1,but memory is not cleared.